# How can I add a label "Select an Agent" and make the value null as the first option to this dropdownlist?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

```
@Html.DropDownList("AgentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The list of agents come from a Viewbag called AgentId which are read directly from the database.

```
Viewbag. AgentId = new Selectlist (db.Agents, "ID", "AgentCentre", distribution.AgentId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this overload which accepts the option label as the third parameter

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code would be

```
@Html.DropDownList("AgentId", null,"Select an agent", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This will add a option with text "Select an agent" and no value attribute.